# Measure memory usage by running two executables at the same time

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I compiled a code and ran two executables: `exec1` and `exec 2`.
They both have the same code but they are given different inputs.
I am using as operationg system `Kubuntu` (very novice).

- Every executable interacts by using the sqlite library with two databases: one database for `exec1` and another for `exec2`
- Every executable needs to load and parse an xml file

---

## CPU Information

```
processor       : 5
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 44
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x10
cpu MHz         : 2660.022
cache size      : 12288 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 6
core id         : 10
cpu cores       : 6
apicid          : 20
initial apicid  : 20
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
```

---

## Questions

- Is it possible to know if running **both** executables at the same time will affect the speed of both executables?
- How do I measure the amount memory used by every executable?
- Is it possible to do it visually?

---

## Using script

by using the following script (need update):

```
echo "timestamp,VmSize,VmRSS";
while awk '{ printf "%s,%s,%s\n", systime(), $1, $2}' /proc/13417/statm; do sleep 1; done 


timestamp,VmSize,VmRSS
1427295959,92907,49655
1427295960,92907,49655
1427295961,92907,49655
1427295962,92907,49655
1427295964,92907,49655
1427295965,92907,49655
```

---

Comment: For time comparison: as compared to running one after the other?  I'm pretty sure running *two* of them will be no faster than running *one*.

Comment: yes @ScottHunter compared running one after the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to know if running both executables at the same time will affect the speed of both executables?

If running one executable takes N seconds and running two of those executables takes same N seconds (no time difference) then they do not affect each other.

> How do I measure the amount memory used by every executable?

You can use this tiny script to output the timestamp and memory usage in csv format every second.

```
echo "timestamp,VmSizeKB,VmRssKB";
while awk '{ printf "%s,%s,%s\n", systime(), $1 * 4, $2 * 4}' /proc/<pid>/statm; do sleep 1; done
```

Replace `<pid>` with your process id.

> Is it possible to do it visually?

Then import that csv into google docs or another spreadsheet application and build a nice chart. You are only interested in VmRSS column, this is the amount of physical memory used by your process.

Comment: Really interesting I am running it right now. It's much simpler than top.

Comment: well i'll post the results.

Comment: @HaniGoc You used the initial version. The new version multiplies the numbers by 4096 to get measurements in bytes.

Comment: i'll update it. @Maxim can you check the rest of my question. I checked what is the total physical memory of my pc is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Given the precondition that you have (at least) two physical CPU cores available and that your programs do not have huge private working sets, running two instances in parallel will generally be faster than running them one after another. There are cases in which the opposite is true, but usually, under healthy conditions, that will be the case.

Any two instances (concurrent or one after another) will under normal circumstances use the same mapped pages from the buffer cache for executable and readonly data, but concurrently running processes *also* have a higher likelihood of having the memory in the last cache level, and they run instructions on different CPU cores *at the same time*.
Also, two instances which are created with `fork` (see below) will only run CRT initialization and any initialization code prior to `fork` once and don't need an extra shell.

(Now of course, those advantages become totally insignificant and turn into disadvantages if your processes do a lot of locking or a lot of concurrent unbuffered I/O or if they consume huge amounts of memory, so they start interfering in an unhealthy way. Hence, "usually", not always.)

The easiest way of running the same program twice (well, thrice actually, if you count the parent) and measuring (and comparing whether it's faster than one invocation) is to call `fork` twice and do the measuring yourself.  Actually calling `fork` *once* would be enough for running the two instances, but then it's a little more twisted to do the measuring that you want to do.

After you [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) twice, you have two child processes running (which can then do whatever they're supposed to do). The parent process gets the current time with [`clock_gettime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) and blocks on `waitpid` (twice).

Following `waitpid`, the parent calls `clock_gettime` again and does a call to [`times`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html).

You now have available:

- a start time
- an end time (from which you can subtract the start time)
- the user and kernel time of the children

With that, you can tell exactly how long it took in real time to execute the child (children) and how much CPU time (user and kernel) they consumed doing that.

Comment: I think my question isn't full.
@Damon concering your comment about **concurrent unbuffered I/O**. 
1. The program that I am running interacts by using the sqlite library with two databases : 1 database for exec1 and another for exec. 
2. It also need to load and parse an xml file. 

are these considered as unbuffered I/O?

Comment: Well, normal I/O is buffered, most data that you read is fetched long before due to readahead. Data that you write goes into buffer pages which are "dirty" and lazily written back. Insofar, you do not normally see much of an effect when two processes make use of the disk -- on the contrary, they might want to read the same pages. However, when talking to a database (same database) or when doing unbuffered writes in general, you will very soon start to feel the fact that the disk is a physical entity which can only do so and so many requests per second.

Comment: It depends on what level of consistency you have configured, but usually your database (sqlite or whichever) will need to write a journal (not necessarily unbuffered, but often), and will have to lock either rows or complete tables, or the underlying database file (depending on implementation) to apply changes. Insofar, yes, two processes competing may very well have adverse effects.

Answer (score 0):

You could run

```
myprogram argone &
myprogram argtwo &
```

to run two processes running the same program in the background.

You might also be interested by `batch` and `nohup` and `top`

Comment: Can you help in the analysis a little bit @Basile Starynkevitch.